# Ubuntu One Support for AppRadio

Tags: ubuntu-one

Many iPhone apps like pandora, rdio, and aupeo! have support for AppRadio will Ubuntu One support the device in the future? It would be awesome to be able to us the interface directly on my App Radio - it would encourage me to keep up my subscription and support the project.

http://pioneerelectronics.com/PUSA/Car/AppRadio

Answer (score 1):

Interesting! I'd like to look into this: can you describe briefly what you like about appradio?